# how to call a callback function after certain amount of time

Tags: python, twisted

I'm using Twisted along with Txmongo lib.
In the following function, I want to invoke cancelTest() 5 secs later. But the code does not work. How can I make it work?

```
from twisted.internet import task

def diverge(self, d):
    if d == 'Wait':
        self.flag = 1
        # self.timeInit = time.time()
        clock = task.Clock()
        for ip in self.ips:
            if self.factory.dictQueue.get(ip) is not None:
                self.factory.dictQueue[ip].append(self)
            else:
                self.factory.dictQueue[ip] = deque([self])
                # self.factory.dictQueue[ip].append(self)

        log.msg("-----------------the queue after wait")
        log.msg(self.factory.dictQueue)
###############################HERE, this does not work
        self.dtime = task.deferLater(clock, 5, self.printData)
#############################
        self.dtime.addCallback(self.cancelTest)
        self.dtime.addErrback(log.err)
    else:
        self.cancelTimeOut()
        d.addCallback(self.dispatch)
        d.addErrback(log.err)



def sendBackIP(self):
    self.ips.pop(0)
    log.msg("the IPs: %s" % self.ips)

    d = self.factory.service.checkResource(self.ips)

    d.addCallback(self.diverge) ###invoke above function
    log.msg("the result from checkResource: ")
    log.msg()
```

Answer (score 0):

In general `reactor.callLater()` is the function you want. So if the function needs to be called 5 seconds later, your code would look like this:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.callLater(5, cancelTest)
```

One thing that is strange is that your `task.deferLater` implementation should also work. However without seeing more of your code I don't think I can help you more other than stating that it's strange :)

## References

- https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#callbacks
  http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.base.ReactorBase.html#callLater

Comment: It's not strange at all :-) Clock() is a deterministic mock implementation of IReactorTime, so the clock would never move unless clock.advance(5) is called.

Answer (score 0):

you're doing almost everything right; you just didn't get the Clock part correctly.

**twisted.internet.task.Clock** is a deterministic implementation of IReactorTime, which is mostly used in unit/integration testing for getting a deterministic output from your code; you shouldn't use that in production.

So, what should you use in production? **reactor**! In fact, all production reactor implementations implement the IReactorTime interface.

Just use the following import and function call:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
# (omissis)
self.dtime = task.deferLater(reactor, 5, self.printData)
```

Just some sidenotes:

in your text above the snippet, you say that you want to invoke cancelTest after five seconds, but in the code you actually invoke printData; of course if printData just prints something, doesn't raise and returns an immediate value, this will cause the cancelTest function to be executed immediately after since it's a chained callcack; **but if you want to actually be 100% sure, you should call cancelTest within deferLater, not printData**.

Also, I don't understand if this is a kind of "timeout"; please be advised that such callback will be triggered in all situations, even if the tests take less than five seconds. If you need a cancelable task, you should use reactor.callLater directly; that will NOT return a deferred you can use, but will let you cancel the scheduled call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still have questions: since this program uses internet.TCPServer and other service modules so the reactor is actually behind the scene, if I use reactor like what you said, would it be 2 reactors? and what do I do with it?

Comment: reactor is actually a pattern, well described in the POSA2 book: http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471606952.html

There's only one reactor. In Twisted, you're probably using SelectReactor or EPollReactor if you're under Linux. When such module is imported for the first time, it instantiates the default reactor if it wasn't already installed: https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/src/twisted/internet/reactor.py

So it's the TCPServer which, under the hood, uses the reactor, and not vice-verse. You can safely ignore it until you need a specific implementation.